# Is the following set a closed set?

Tags: general-topology

I am not really an expert in this kind of topic, so maybe I am looking at the following question with the wrong approach (geometric).

Consider two real variables $x_1$ and $x_2$, and as well $z := x_1 - x_2$.

Of course, I can see that the set $S_1 := \{z : ||z|| \leq 1\}$ is compact. However, I do not know what I can say about the set $S_2 := \{x_1, x_2: ||x_1 - x_2|| \leq 1\}$, whether is closed or not.

Maybe my problem is with the geometric interpretation since it is very clear that $S_1$ is a ball and I can easily check when $z$ belongs to the ball or not. However, concerning $S_2$, all $x_1$ and $x_2$ (given the constraint) *potentially* belong to $S_2$.

Comment: You can find this out yourself! Try to take a convergent sequence in $S_2$ and see what happens to the constraint in the limit. Or write $S_2$ as preimage of $S_1$ under a function $\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$ and think about how this could help.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jan. Indeed, that is how to address the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S_2$ is certainly closed, as it is a preimage of the closed interval $(-\infty, 1]$ using a continuous function.

However, $S_2$ is **not** bounded, which can be shown quite easily by noticing it contains the entire line $\{(x_1,x_2)|x_1=x_2\}$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you mean

$$S_2 = \{(x_1,x_2): \lVert x_1 - x_2 \rVert \le 1\},$$

that is the set of ordered pairs $(x_1, x_2)$.

Your geometric interpretation is still usefull then, just in 2 dimensions now. I plotted (a part) of the set in Wolfram Alpha:

[image: Plot of x-1 <= y <= x+1 from -5 to 5]

Of course, the strip continues on both ends (upper right, lower left). Does that help you to decide if it is closed?